# AJAX to ASHX with JSON data. Need help processing data

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, ashx

I am trying to send a list of ids to a generic handler which will process these ids and do further logic. I am sending the list of ids such as `items: ["32", "33"]`. I am not able to get the ids of these items. I've tried to serialize, deserialize, and place the values in an object without any luck. Could you help me see where I am going wrong in this process?

============JavaScript ==============

```
$.ajax({
     type: "post",
     data: JSON.stringify({ 'items': itemIds }),
     url: 'deleteItems.ashx',
     success: function (data) {
       console.log('working'); 
       console.log(data); 
      },
      error: function (request, err) {
       console.log(err);
      }
});
```

============= DATA RETURNED FROM delteItems.ashx in console.log =============

"items": [
  "39"
]{"items":["39"]}

============ DeleteItems.ashx =================

```
//not sure if this is needed
public class inventoryItems
{
    public List<string> items { get; set; }
}


public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
   context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        string json = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();  
         //iif I use a list in DeserializeObject with the inventoryItems class, I return an error in my ajax file.        
        dynamic inventoryItems = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);             
        foreach (var obj in inventoryItems)
        {
            context.Response.Write(obj);
            // return each id and do more logic

        }
```

- DeleteItems.ashx is returning data as "text/plain"

Comment: something strange here: you send them under "items" and try to get them as "itemsObject", is it normal? (maybe it's a asp.net specificity, i don't know). Have you also tried to get the values from headers rather than query string too?

Comment: I removed that line of code. I never use that.